# how you random for xhouse

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Hello everyone hope you're all well

I have problem I don't know how to use random so that the house that i created each time i refresh the page  the X position change so that the house appears in different X .

Thank you

this is my code;

```
var floorPos_y;
var xhouse;
var yhouse;


function setup() {

    createCanvas(1000, 755);
    floorPos_y = height * 3 / 4; //NB. we are now using a variable for the floor position

    xhouse = 0;
    yhouse = 0;

    var xhouse = random(100, width);

}


function draw() {


    background(100, 155, 255); //fill the sky blue

    // House Code
    //xhouse = 30;

    yhouse = 366;


    noStroke();
    fill(255);
    text("house", 100, height * 0.6);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(xhouse, yhouse, 180, 200);//main body of the house
    fill(165, 42, 42);
    triangle(xhouse, yhouse, xhouse + 90, yhouse - 116, xhouse + 180, yhouse);// tope of the house
    fill(255, 255, 220);
    rect(xhouse + 5, yhouse + 24, 55, 60);
    rect(xhouse + 110, yhouse + 24, 55, 60);

    fill(0, 0, 230);
    rect(xhouse + 60, yhouse + 114, 50, 80);
    fill(255, 255, 30);
    ellipse(xhouse + 100, yhouse + 164, 13, 13);


}

function mousePressed() {
    xposition = mouseX
    yposition = mouseY
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: I Just found out the was my mistake thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to properly format your code. Right now it's pretty hard to read. Also please try to debug your code: I'd start by printing out the value of `xhouse` before you try to use it in the `draw()` function:

```
console.log("xHouse: " + xhouse);
```

This will show you that `xhouse` is undefined, which is a pretty big hint.

Taking a closer look at your `xhouse` variable, you might notice that you're **declaring** a variable named `xhouse` at the top of your sketch:

```
var xhouse;
```

So far so good. Then in the `setup()` function, you're declaring **another** variable named `xhouse`, and setting its value:

```
var xhouse = random(100,width);
```

But note that because you're using the `var` keyword, this is creating a **different** variable than the one at the top of your sketch. The variable at the top of your sketch still has no value. In other words, its value is `undefined`.

To fix your problem, you need to **declare** the variable at the top of your sketch, and then **initialize** the variable in the `setup()` function. In other words, get rid of the `var` keyword in the `setup()` function:

```
xhouse = random(100,width);
```

If you're having other problems, please try to debug your problem by printing out the value of the variables you're using. Good luck.